# Fliepicker.io - How to add fields to the widgets modal dialog?

Tags: filepicker.io

I use filepicker.io to handle upload. But I want the user to provide additional data related to the uploaded file, so basically I would need to add to the modal some comboboxes and text inputs. Is it possible by using the widget approach with the filepicker.constructWidget call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible, constructWidget only accepts addition options listed here https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file_ingestion/widgets/programming?v=v1 and a type which can be 'filepicker' or 'filepicker-dragdrop'. You would need to try a different approach i.e. add the text inputs after the modal is called and files uploaded.